# how to read a string

Tags: c, string, char

I´m new to programming and I'm still trying to figure out how everything works out but I want to write a string what should be used later on with adding characters, split the text, upper/lower cases and so on. Right now I am stuck on the reading part of the string and this is what I have so far:

```
int A, str[100];    
printf("Write the text you want to use:\n");
char A;
scanf("%c", &A);
```

When I run the program it just jumps over this part, is it because I just wrote char A instead of str?

Comment: You probably want to use `fgets`.

Comment: "jumps over this part" -- where is the rest of the code? Why is `A` declared twice?

Comment: why are you telling `scanf` you want a character (`%c`) when you say you want to read in a string (`%s`)?

Comment: Surely there's an example in your beginner-level C programming book? You'll need to study strings there, before using them. They are normally `char` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong. First of all you are declaring two times A, with two different types - you should get an error there because you can only declare a variable once.

Secondly, you should indeed store the string in str[100], as it is an array (which can store multiple variables, one in each element, therefore 100 in your case). You should also use `char` arrays, not `int`. `A` is also useless in your case because you will store the string in `str`.

It is better to use `fgets` for strings, because it is more secure. Also, `scanf` will stop reading after the first space in your string, which in most cases is not what you want.

This should work, I also added explanations:

```
printf("Write the text you want to use:\n");
char str[100];
fgets(str,100,stdin); // 100 is the number of characters to store, stdin indicates that you are reading from the standard input, what the user is typing

printf("String: %s",str); // just for verification
```

Comment: You should also mention that `fgets` will include a `\n` in the string as that's a common gotcha people fall foul of

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You have declared the variable "A" first as an integer, and later as a character datatype, this will generate a conflict during compilation. This can be rectified by using different variable names for both.

After that, answer to your problems can be-

1. Strings are stored as an array of characters of arrays in C, not just by a single char. So you should declare the desired variable to obtain the string from the user as variable_name char[100] and then use this in fgets.

eg:

```
printf("Enter the input text:\n");
char string[50];
fgets(str,100,stdin); // the max length of string that can be taken is depicted by 50.

printf("Input was: %s",string); // check your string variable contents, mind the %s used to mark string variables in C
```

2. You can use the [string library](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/string-handling-functions) of C, which has a lot of advanced functionalities with an easy and simplified syntax. Go through the link, you'll find it much easier than anything else